# Populate an object referenced by another object

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I've a list of products, each of one with its own options. For example:

- Blue Dress (S - L)
- Red Dress (XS - S - M)

*Blue Dress* and *Red Dress* are the products, *S*, *L*, *XS*, *S* and *M* are the options. The options model has a reference to the product model, I would like to retrieve all the products and then list their own options.

I would like to achieve it with one query only, my problem is that I start from the product that has no link to its options. So I start finding all the products, and with a nested *then* with a foreach loop I get all its options. Then I try assign the option to the product object (in my case *productElem* inside a *forEach*), but when I retrieve it out of the scope of course it is empty. How to populate the options starting from a query of the products?

Product Schema:

```
var schema = new Schema({
  imagePath: {type: String},
  title: {type: String, required: true},
  description: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

Option Schema:

```
var productOptionSchema = new Schema({
  type: {type: String, enum: ['grams'], default: 'grams', required: true},
  value: {type: String, required: true},
  price: {type: Number, required:true},
  product: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required:true}
});
```

Here I try to get the options after finding the products

```
router.get('/shop/products/list', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
  Product.find()
    .then(function (products) {
      products.forEach(function(productElem) {
        ProductOption.find({product: productElem._id})
          .then(function (options) {
            productElem['options'] = [];
            options.forEach(function(optionElem) {
              productElem['options'].push(optionElem);
            });
          });
      });
      res.render('shop/listProduct', {user:req.user, csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), messages:messages, partialCustom: 
      });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log('Error ' + err.code + ': ', err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Failed to get the Product List from the DB: ' + err);
    });
});
```

Comment: your problem is not quite clear. Please edit the question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

There are some flaws in your code. the `forEach` loop is trying to find all the options based on `product ID`, which looks like an obvious approach here, but the problem here is asynchronous nature of the `find()` method.

Because of the asynchronous nature of the `find()`, `forEach` loop gets completed without waiting for the result of individual `find()`, as a result of which `options` is not yet populated . And after the loop it justs render 'shops/listProduct', which obviously doesn't have the product options.

What you can do is push all the `find()` in a `promises` array, wait for all promises to return using `Promise.all()`. Do `res.render('shops/listProduct',{...})` after all the promises are successfully completed.

**Alternate Method:**

I have a much simpler method to achieve what you want using `aggregation`.

Try this:

```
ProductOption.aggregate([{
    $group : {
        _id : product,
        options : {$push : "$$ROOT"}
    }
},{
    $lookup : {
        from : "products",
        localField : "_id",
        foreignField : "_id",
        as : "product"
    }
},{
    $unwind : {
        path : "$product",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : true
    }
},{
    $project : {
        _id : "$product._id"
        imagePath : "$product.imagePath",
        title : "$product.title",
        description : "$product.description",
        options : "$options"
    }
}],function(err,result){
    //result will have all the products with their options
});
```

`$group` will group the options based on the `product`(i.e product ID)  `$lookup` will populate the product object, and `$project` will return you the result in the way that you want.

Read about [mongodb Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/), [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to understand it better.